# How can I use Windows Explorer Search to find a file under a specific folder no matter how deep the subdirectories go?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, search

Each of my company's jobs has a unique folder on our Win2k3r2 server. J:\[department]\[folder]. Under each job there are a plethora of folders and sub folders, one being "sales photos". I would like to search all "sales photos" folders for contained jpeg files. I've tried "*.jpg in:'sales photos'" but it doesn't fully work. It only returns jpgs that are contained directly by 'sales photos'. Is it possible to find all jpgs under 'sales photos' no matter how deep the sub-directories go? i.e. I'd like to find .\sales photos\1.jpg as well as .\sales photos\dir1\1.jpg as well as .\sales photos\dir1\dir2\1.jpg.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't display files in sub-folders more than 1 level deep. I've removed my answer and will let you know if I find any way to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in Explorer but you could do that with [FileLocator Pro](http://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorpro). It has an inclusion/exclusion filter feature that matches the whole path. Use '+' or '-' to specify if you're including or excluding the term, e.g.

```
J:\Department;+Sales Photos
```

Where all results must have 'Sales Photos' matched at some level in the path.

Comment: That sounds like what I need.  I'll let you know if it works after I get the demo installed and figure out how to use it.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the last poster, get something, *anything* besides Windows Explorer, each new version seems to be purposely more & more crippled, otherwise:

`Tools / FolderOptions / Search / [Check] Include SubFolders when typing in SearchBox`.